# What protocol does Google Analytics use in the standard API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, network-protocols, service-accounts

I am using GA API for retrieving some data. The Key file .p12 is used for encryption.

I wonder what protocol is the communication made through. Is it SSH or HTTPS? Would you also tell how could I figure it myself?

Comment: What makes you think it's ssh?

Comment: Probably lack of knowledge of protocols.

Comment: So what makes you think it's something else than http(s)? Where does this question come from?

Comment: I guess it is because I know that I can use key files for SSH connection on SFTP for example and I was thinking it may have been SSH protocol then.

Comment: the p12 file is old way of authenticating service accounts now we use .json file the legacy p12 file still works though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the Google APIs are Rest APIs and are though web services.   As far as I know most of them use Https.  I cant actually think of anything off the top of my head that isn't.

End point for Google Analytics v4

```
https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com
```

End point for Google Analytics v3

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga
```

I would have to dig though the code to be sure what the Embeded api uses but my guess is its the same endpoint as V3.

Check out the definition of rest api when you have a chance if you are interested.